# evaluating an expression to true in a if statement with Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm having serious biggies trying to figure out how to evaluate an expression in a If statement using Tcl. This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
#The next line executes wish - wherever it is \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

set apid "/var/run/apache2.pid"

set apsta [file exist $apid]

if { $apsta == 1 }

{
    set result ":)"
}

else

{
    set result ":("
}

label .status -text $result
pack .status
```

and this is what I get from the terminal:

```
# wan27
Error in startup script: wrong # args: no script following " $apsta == 1 " argument
    while executing
"if { $apsta == 1 }"
    (file "/usr/bin/wan27" line 9)
```

I'm just trying to output a happy smiley if Apache is running, a sad one if Apache is stopped - based upon the boolean condition whether or not the file "/var/run/apache2.pid" exists ...

Comment: You've pretty much got to use One True Brace style with Tcl (pick your own indentation rules though, but I prefer 3 or 4 spaces) since otherwise the language ends statements at the first newline. Your only alternative is to add in extra backslashes at the end of the lines you want to continue, but I think that sucks *far* more. (Alternatively, write things on one very long line with semicolons between commands. Ugly, but no brace/indent troubles.)

Comment: ok, i get it now, and that would explain the "no script following " thingy. The interpreter was expecting a brace in the same line then the if statement. i also noticed that the keyword if needed to be separated by a space and could not be glued to the evaluation symbol such as if{}

Comment: Also note that `[file exists...]` returns a true/false result, so you don't have to explicitly compare the result to 1:  `if {$apsta} {...}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax of a Tcl `if` statement is

```
if condition statement else statement
```

which must be on one line. Braces allow continuation across lines and their placement is mandatory:

```
if { $apsta == 1 } {
    set result ":)"
} else {
    set result ":("
}
```

As you have it written, Tcl sees

```
if { $apsta == 1 }
```

and stops there yielding a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

MSW have already given you the correct answer but I think a little bit more explanation is needed to clear up some other confusions you are having based on your comments.

I will first explain things using non-tcl terminology since I think it is less confusing that way.

In tcl, `if` is not a statement. `if` is a function. That is the reason why the opening brace need to be on the same line: because a newline terminates the list of arguments to a function. For example, in the following code:

```
a b c d
e f
```

the Tcl interpreter will see two function calls. The first to function `a` with arguments b, c and d and the second to function `e` with a single argumrnt f. Similarly, in the following:

```
if a
   b
```

Tcl sees a call to the function `if` with a single argument. Since `if` expects at least two arguments it (not the interpreter itself) throws an error complaining about wrong number of arguments.

This also explains why there must be a space between if and its first argument. It's just because in tcl names of variables and functions are literally allowed to contain almost anything including spaces, commas and non-printing characters like NUL. For example, you can define a function called `a{b}`:

```
proc a{b} {} {puts HA!}
a{b} ;# <-- prints out HA!
```

So if you do something like:

```
if{x} {y}
```

tcl will complain that the function `if{x}` is not defined.

`if` is not the only thing that works like this. Tcl doesn't really have keywords, just a standard library of built-in functions like `for`, `foreach` and `while`. The same rules apply to all of them.

---

*not really important:*

On a side, the `if` function in tcl works like the ternary operator in C: it returns a value. In fact you can do the following:

```
# It is unfortunate that this "give" function is not built in.
# We use it to return something from if without actually
# calling return:
proc give {x} {return $x}

set something [if {$x} {give "Very true indeed."} {give "Unfortunately false."}]
```